# Rails - How to Move a PaperClip Model to Another Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

Rails 3 app with paperclip.

Given a Paperclip File Model, how can you move that paperclip File to different paperclip, say image gallery? Which would have different processing rules etc?

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you intend to post this question every day?

Comment: Just trying to solve the problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've just tried the following:

Given two models, with a `picture` attachment and their own Paperclip configurations, say: Gallery1 and Gallery2.

Given I had one object in Gallery1 with a picture already attached.

Make:

```
Gallery2.create(:picture => Gallery1.first.picture)
```

And it creates the picture properly resized with the constraints of Gallery2.